# How to know the existence of solution of algebra equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

For example we want to find a and b such that a**v**+b**w**=**0** (bold text means vector, otherwise scalar)

Usually we would just solve the equation. But before solving that equation we need one assumption: that the solution exists. How can we know that the solution exists?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks that sounds much better

Answer (score 0):

you have either that only solution is $ a = 0 $ and $ b = 0$ or there is some $ k = \frac{a}{b}$. The former case means two vectors are independent each other, the later case means that two vectors are parallel or dependent or one is anothe scaler multiplier depending on where the question occurs.

In linear algebra, sometimes we just want to know if there is a trivial solution (a = 0  and b = 0) and non-trivial solution. Then we can inteprete the solution in terms of relation of vectors: independent or dependent. For non-trivial solution, we might just to find a normalized solution such as finding eigenvectors.

Comment: Not related to this, but I would suggest you mark all of the answers to your questions as "answered your question" if they answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one may proceed with solving first, then plug the result(s) back into the original equations to test if they are solutions that exist. (assuming we don't talk complex analysis)

If the solution *doesn't* exist, then we either won't be able to solve it or the solution won't work when we plug it back in.

In the case that we won't be *able* to solve it, that possibly means that a) you don't have the required skills or b) the solution is not solvable by any known means.  If it is the former, ask on this site.  If it is the latter, then check it as unsolvable.

**Note** that a solution may not have closed form.  For example, there will *always* be 5 solutions (possibly not unique) to a quintic polynomial.  However, the quintic polynomial may not be reducible.  In this scenario, there exists a solution that is not findable by exact methods, you must approximate.

Comment: But we just cant solve the equation because we do not know the existence of the solution?

Comment: @Jin It is rather the process of solving that often determines if the solution exists.